# How to store simple data for standalone java application

Tags: java, json, search, local

Assume I have a long list of People with some basic characteristics:

Matt, 27, male

Anne, 49, female

etc...

I want to store this data locally for a standalone desktop application that does not require access to the internet. My current method is writing the names to a json file and reading them all in to a Person class in java when the program is opened; however, I did not think this was efficient as the data only needs to be accessed if someone is performing a search.

So I considered a simple JSONparser, let's say searchNameInFile("Matt", "data.json") { return person; }, but I did not know if this was a good way to store the data with regards to efficiency. I considered sqlite shortly, but I am only storing one table of data and thought it might be overkill. What is an appropriate, efficient method for storing and searching local data?

Comment: That’s somewhat subjective - a database solution increases the complexity of your code and/or you library dependencies and the installation of the app (SQLite needs to install its platform depended binaries). If the amount of data you’re storing is relatively small (1000s of rows) and the time overhead relatively unimportant (seconds over milliseconds) and the queries relatively simple, a sql database may be more complex then is required. However - I typically fall back on h2 as it’s a pure java implementation (ie no installation) of a sql database that can run in standalone mode

Comment: I've done a number of projects in the past where I stored and managed data in a XML format. I then used xPath to query the structure as needed. While this doesn't require a lot in the form of setting up or dependencies, it's still rather complex (xPath queries aren't for the faint hearted).  JSON also has a concept of xPath, [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), I've not used, so I can speak to it's complexity or overhead, but it's another choice over using a traditional sql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really  think you should reconsider SQLite.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

Your data will be stored locally in a file that can be easily queried with standard Java SQL stuff. It does not require any server software or an internet connection.

If you don't want to use SQLite, here are two possible ways, depending on what you do care about.

If you only care about time complexity, but have plenty of memory to throw around, you could store your data in an efficient structure such as a HashMap, and use Java's built in Serializable to write the HashMap out to a file, and read it back in on next start.

```
//Where Person is a data class that implements Serializable and contains your desired fields
public void saveData(HashMap<String, Person> people) {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("people.txt"));
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
    o.writeObject(people);
    o.close();
    f.close();
}
public HashMap<String, Person> loadData() {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("people.txt"));
    ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
    HashMap<String, Person> data = (HashMap<String, Person>) oi.readObject();
    oi.close();
    fi.close();
    return data;
}
```

If you don't mind O(n) search times, then your current solution of re-reading the file on every search is fine.

Comment: I think I will use SQLite based on your suggestion and the one below. I wanted the data to be re-usable by another program, let's say a web app, in the future so I decided not to use java serializable a while ago and switch to JSON for reading in some of the other, non-relational?, objects. A local database will also allow the data to easily be re-used. Thanks for the help!

Comment: H2 is (IMHO) a better solution as it’s a pure java database, which can run in standalone mode and doesn’t require any native drivers/code to be installed - otherwise, it’s just a sql database like SQLite

Comment: Sounds good, I might look into that for my future projects. I have only ever used SQLite in the past so that's what I recommended.

Comment: H2 sounds perfect. I was also concerned about a user having to install sqlite drivers, so that solves that problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider another Simple in-memory DB as H2. It will save data in a relational db that is store in your computer as a file. The advantage is the high-retrieval speed benchmark it has.
[H2](http://www.h2database.com)

Advantage is that configuration is as simple as create the DB object and configure it to use in-memory file.

Comment: I think this will lost the data when we restart the application

Answer (score 0):

> it might be overkill

Re-inventing the wheel would be the real overkill. There are plenty libraries and methods out there for storing and loading data.

Since you want to store the data locally in a file, but also want to search in the data, an embedded SQL database should be a good option for you. Either SQLite, h2 or HSQL.

For acessing the data, you can use anything from plain JDBC up to *Spring Data JPA*

Comment: Thanks! I have only heard of sqlite, but I am going to look into the other ones you mentioned as well. And I don't know much about the spring framework, which is what I think you are referring to, but I do know jdbc so that is likely what I will use.

Comment: _Spring Data JPA_ works on top on JPA, which in turn works on top of JDBC. I've mentioned it, because with _Spring Boot_ and _Spring Data JPA_ combined you could write your persistence layer with nearly no code. See this guide for a complete example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Thanks for that link, I've bookmarked it to read more about as it looks like a simple way to accomplish this task with much less code. I am definitely going to read more about it!